# Match in df1$col1 in df2 and output value in df2$col1 into df1$col2

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I have two data frames.

```
symbols <- c("Santa", "Elves", "Candy Cane", "Reindeers", "Cats",
             "Turkey", "Mashed Potatoes", "Cranberry Sauce", "Dogs",
             "Eggs", "Chocolates with cream", "Bunnies", "Flowers", "Donut")


df1 <- data.frame(symbols)

df1
                 symbols
1                  Santa
2                  Elves
3             Candy Cane
4              Reindeers
5                   Cats
6                 Turkey
7        Mashed Potatoes
8        Cranberry Sauce
9                   Dogs
10                  Eggs
11 Chocolates with cream
12               Bunnies
13               Flowers
14                 Donut

holiday <- c("Christmas", "Thanksgiving", "Easter")
v1 <- c("Santa", "Turkey", "Eggs")
v2 <- c("Elves", "Mashed Potatoes", "Chocolates with cream")
v3 <- c("Candy Canes", "Cranberry Sauce", "Bunnies")
v4 <- c("Reindeers", NA, "Flowers")

df2 <- data.frame(holiday, v1, v2, v3, v4)

df2
       holiday     v1
1    Christmas  Santa
2 Thanksgiving Turkey
3       Easter   Eggs
                     v2              v3
1                 Elves     Candy Canes
2       Mashed Potatoes Cranberry Sauce
3 Chocolates with cream         Bunnies
         v4
1 Reindeers
2      <NA>
3   Flowers
```

If anything in df1$symbols match with any of the values in df2 (df2$holiday, df2$v1, df2$v2, df2$v3, df2$v4), I want it to output the df2$holiday value into a new column in df1.

Ideally, I'll have a df1 that looks like this:

```
    df1
                 symbols      holiday
1                  Santa    Christmas
2                  Elves    Christmas
3             Candy Cane    Christmas
4              Reindeers    Christmas
5                   Cats         <NA>
6                 Turkey Thanksgiving
7        Mashed Potatoes Thanksgiving
8        Cranberry Sauce Thanksgiving
9                   Dogs         <NA>
10                  Eggs       Easter
11 Chocolates with cream       Easter
12               Bunnies       Easter
13               Flowers       Easter
14                 Donut         <NA>
```

I think one way I could do it is split df2 up and then do left_join for every column:

```
df2_v1 <- data.frame(df2$holiday, df2$v1)
df2_v2 <- data.frame(df2$holiday, df2$v2)
df2_v3 <- data.frame(df2$holiday, df2$v3)
df2_v4 <- data.frame(df2$holiday, df2$v4)

Then I can use left_join for each df1 with df2_v#. For example:

df1_x <- left_join(df1, df2_v1, by = c("symbols" = "df2.v1"))
```

I can then coalesce or use some ifelse logic to get a clean df1$holiday column, but this is pretty time consuming if there are more columns in df2.

Is there a faster way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

```
library( data.table )
setDT(df1);setDT(df2)
#join on molten df2
df1[ melt(df2, id.vars = "holiday"), 
     holiday := i.holiday, on = .(symbols = value)]

#                  symbols      holiday
# 1:                 Santa    Christmas
# 2:                 Elves    Christmas
# 3:            Candy Cane         <NA>
# 4:             Reindeers    Christmas
# 5:                  Cats         <NA>
# 6:                Turkey Thanksgiving
# 7:       Mashed Potatoes Thanksgiving
# 8:       Cranberry Sauce Thanksgiving
# 9:                  Dogs         <NA>
#10:                  Eggs       Easter
#11: Chocolates with cream       Easter
#12:               Bunnies       Easter
#13:               Flowers       Easter
#14:                 Donut         <NA>
```